# Anchor Link With Two Fixed Navigations - Complex

Tags: javascript, jquery, css, position, anchor

Basically I have a fixed header with a navigation in it that is always attached to the top of the window. Then I have another fixed element which is a Pagination but its only attaches its self to the top of window when its is scrolled to!

This pagination has anchor links that link to different sections on the page! However when you click on the links it covered the content which both fixed floating elements.

Here is the example: http://www.chudz.co.uk/test/

If you scroll down you will see the pagination attach itself to the header navigation! Then if you click on "A" in the pagination you will see what happens! The content gets covered! (A is the only link that works atm sorry).

Anyone know of a solution I could use?

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is the JavaScript work around for this problem. 
First, change the name attribute to id attribute in the head links like this.

```
<h2><a id="a">Authors - A</a></h2>
```

Then add this script into your bottom script.

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    $("#pagination a").click(function(event){ 
        event.preventDefault();
        var o =  $( $(this).attr("href") ).offset();   
        var sT = o.top - 151; // 151 is the header height + navigation height 
        window.scrollTo(0,sT);
    });
});
```

Comment: That worked! Only problem is when the pagination isnt set to fixed before its scroll to if someone click on B the content is still hidden. Any idea how to fix that?

Comment: Would you elaborate more and update your test page? So that I would give a try.

Comment: Sorry Derek, it was just sometimes I did to the CSS that broke it I fixed it now working spot on thanks!

Answer (score 1):

Your fixed pagination is not taking up any space in the dom.

You should use 'id' instead of 'name', then add a class to the anchor, position it absolutely and move it upwards with a negative margin (the same as the height of the pagination). This will ensure that the anchor starts below the pagination.

Comment: Why use a script to fix this when there is a CSS soloution? Just add a class to your anchors with the style: margin: -151px